# Cannot resolve symbol DynamoDBMapper

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect my android app to AWS DynamoDB but I cannot create DynamoDBMapper object and import that library:

```
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.*;
```

I follow this tutorail:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html

I added those lines to Grandle script as well:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.+'
```

Is that library outdated or I missed sth?

Answer (score 2):

Only the last dependency is needed. Please clean your workspace and rebuild it.

Comment: Actualy i needed other compile:

 compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.+'

Now it works